# How can I add a Continuous LOD for a single object?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have got a single object.
A heightmap.

[image]

(Ignore the flag and the water - We have imaginations, right? ;) )

However, the issue is that I display this as a single display list. Therefore, I cannot "check the distance" of the map from the player, nor make the map less detailed, because I am only able to treat the map as a single object.

I have tried using shaders, however these are too late in the pipeline to be able to affect performance (If I use a shader to cut out EVERYTHING in the entire game, the game still lags as if it has everything else).

So, how can I add a Continuous Level Of Detail to the terrain, before it is too late, without splitting it into a ton of different objects (And even that wouldn't work well)?

Comment: Check out tesselation. https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation

Comment: By "I have tried using shaders", I take it you don't mean geometry shaders? Just vertex and fragment?

Comment: @Tommy Errr... Are there other types of shaders? o.O

Comment: I'd start by ditching the display lists. DLs are outdated for well over a decade; in fact the first drafts for OpenGL-2 released in 2001 were discussing the removal of DLs, already then. However it took until OpenGL-3 core for the step to be actually made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your map up into squares that you can display independently and only create those mesh objects when the player comes close enough to potentially render, and only render when inside the sight of the player.

besides that you can use a [tesselation shader](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tessellation) to create the continuous level of detail. it involves drawing flat quads and using the control shader to say how many vertices must be drawn and the evaluation shader to displace them upwards based on the height map (that you pass in as a texture).

or to be radical you can create a flat mesh that is fine grained in the center and decreases in detail further out, then using the vertex shader you can displace the vertices with the height map, the center remains under the camera but you use the position of the camera to offset the sampled coordinates of the height map (and texture map)